# How do I use Freenode IRC with SASL in Adium?

Tags: encryption, adium, irc

I received the following error when trying to join Freenode with Adium:

`*** Notice -- You need to identify via SASL to use this server`

I understand why they want me to use SASL in my case, and I can see this is a common problem. I can see that Adium supports SASL, and I can find the help ticket that prompted the Adium dev group to add SASL support.

What I can't find is... how to use SASL in Adium. I don't see any options for enabling SASL or configuring it or anything. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Is there an option for something like a NickServ password?

Comment: There are two username/password options: one for the IRC server and one for the proxy. I have entered a pw for the IRC server, but I haven't registered yet. I have to connect, first.

Comment: Oh. You'll need to register to use SASL, I think.

Comment: OK, I've registered but I'm getting the same error.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Adium 1.5 doesn't support using SASL for IRC. That will be added in 1.6: https://trac.adium.im/ticket/14478.

In 1.6, there will be a checkbox to activate SASL. When that is activated, the password field is treated as the SASL password.

### The following build can be used successfully: [Adium_1.6hgr5915.dmg](http://nightly.adium.im/adium-adium-1.6/Adium_1.6hgr5915.dmg)

And [this guide](https://www.sweetprocess.com/procedures/298/connect-to-irc-channel-with-adium/#.VbqDGhE5mY0) may help if you have question using it after you've enabled SASL.

Comment: What can be used on mac?

Comment: This build works great: http://nightly.adium.im/adium-adium-1.6/Adium_1.6hgr5915.dmg

Comment: Looks like the Adium website has been broken for several weeks